# undefined method `login' for #<User:0x00007f4ef2e60468>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When someone visits the site and isn't logged in, a user account is automatically created. There's a button to "login as another user" that logs out and redirects to the sign_up page.

Despite this the sign_up page gives the error:

```
undefined method `login' for #<User:0x00007f4ef2e60468>
```

That means that a user is currently logged in, even though the user was logged out and no new user created.

Comment: Can you share the controller or helper, or whatever, where this error is coming from? You are not giving enough here to help fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Devise won't create migrations for adding login attribute to users table, that you want to manually add via

```
rails g migration add_login_to_users login:string
```